# jquery autocomplete list does not stick with parent input element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete, scroll

I'm having some difficulty adapting jqueryUI autocomplete to my site's CSS layout.

Whenever I call the autocomplete function onto an input field, the list opens as expected. Since the input lives within a div that is of fixed height, when the user scrolls that div, the autocomplete list stays fixed.

Has anyone encountered this and know of a workaround? This issue does not occur when the parent div is not fixed in height.

I've made a jsfiddle mockup here: http://jsfiddle.net/NSm7f/1/

here is my sample code:

```
<div class="root">
    <div id="Header">
        <div class='heading'>Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class='box' id="Wrapper">
        <div class='box' id="Leftpanel">
            <p>some text</p>
                <h1>Other stuff</h1>

            <br>
            <br>Autocomplete box:
            <input id="box1">
            <p>some text</p>
                <h1>Other stuff</h1>

            <br>
            <br>Another autocomplete:
            <input id="box2">
            <p>some text</p>
                <h1>Other stuff</h1>

            <br>
            <br>
            <p>some text</p>
                <h1>Other stuff</h1>

            <br>
            <br>
            <p>some text</p>
                <h1>Other stuff</h1>


            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <!--Leftpanel-->
        <div class='box' id="Rightpanel">
            <form>
                <textarea rows="33" cols="45"></textarea>
                <br>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--End rightpanel-->
    </div>
    <!--wrapper-->
</div>
<!--root-->
```

My JS (yes, I have jqueryUI and the default jqueryUI css loaded):

```
 $("#box1").autocomplete({
     source: ['Skull,Nasal', 'Skull,Lacrimal', 'Skull,Inferior Nasal Concha', 'Skull,Maxiallary', 'Skull,Zygomatic', 'Skull,Temporal', 'Skull,Palatine', 'Skull,Parietal', 'Skull,Malleus', 'Skull,Incus', 'Skull,Stapes', 'Skull,Frontal', 'Skull,Ethmoid', 'Skull,Vomer', 'Skull,Sphenoid', 'Skull,Mandible', 'Skull,Occipital', 'Rib 1', 'Rib 2', 'Rib 3', 'Rib 4', 'Rib 5', 'Rib 6', 'Rib 7', 'Rib 8 ', 'Rib 9 ', 'Rib 10 ', 'Coccyx']
 });

 $("input#box2").autocomplete({
     source: ['Skull,Nasal', 'Skull,Lacrimal', 'Skull,Inferior Nasal Concha', 'Skull,Maxiallary', 'Skull,Zygomatic', 'Skull,Temporal', 'Skull,Palatine', 'Skull,Parietal', 'Skull,Malleus', 'Skull,Incus', 'Skull,Stapes', 'Skull,Frontal', 'Skull,Ethmoid', 'Skull,Vomer', 'Skull,Sphenoid', 'Skull,Mandible', 'Skull,Occipital', 'Rib 1', 'Rib 2', 'Rib 3', 'Rib 4', 'Rib 5', 'Rib 6', 'Rib 7', 'Rib 8 ', 'Rib 9 ', 'Rib 10 ', 'Coccyx']
 });
```

and my css:

```
.box {
    float: left;
}
#root {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#Wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#Leftpanel, #Rightpanel {
    vertical-align: top;
}
#Leftpanel {
    width: 57%;
    display: table-cell;
    height:750px;
    color: #B29D72;
    overflow:scroll;
    background-color: #272F44;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin:0.5%
}
#Rightpanel {
    width: 37%;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 750px;
    color: #B2A283;
    background-color: #0D162C;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin:0.5%
}
#Sidebar {
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #B2A283;
    color: #0D162C;
    padding:1%;
    margin:0.5%;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#Sidebar a:link {
    color: #FFF4CB;
}
#Footer {
    width: 97%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #B2A283;
    color: #0D162C;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 0.5%;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#Footer a:link {
    color: #FFF4CB;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
#Footer A:hover {
    color: #CA9221;
}
#Sidebar .slide-out-div {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #29216d;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not involve any scripting and seems to do the trick.

Autocomplete, by default, appends the list to the `body` of the document. If you insert the option to `appendTo: "parent div that is fixed height"` and change the UI-css class for `ui-autocomplete` from postion:fixed to position:relative, the list will follow the div scroll.

I think this is an easier solution to implement, though @Trevor's will also work.

see this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NSm7f/3/

The key is adding this to your document or change the UI-css with:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Best way is to give parent element the class ui-front and the ui-autocomplete takes care of it: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer. Fixes the issue without needing to modify jQuery UI classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option, you can also consolidate your `autocomplete` call so you don't have to call it on each box individually:

```
 var scrollPosition = -1;
 $("[id^=box]").autocomplete({
        source: ['Skull,Nasal', 'Skull,Lacrimal', 'Skull,Inferior Nasal Concha', 'Skull,Maxiallary',  'Skull,Zygomatic',  'Skull,Temporal',  'Skull,Palatine',  'Skull,Parietal',  'Skull,Malleus',  'Skull,Incus',  'Skull,Stapes',  'Skull,Frontal',  'Skull,Ethmoid',  'Skull,Vomer',  'Skull,Sphenoid',  'Skull,Mandible',  'Skull,Occipital',  'Rib 1',  'Rib 2',  'Rib 3',  'Rib 4',  'Rib 5',  'Rib 6',  'Rib 7',  'Rib 8 ',  'Rib 9 ',  'Rib 10 ',  'Coccyx'],
     open: function( event, ui ) {
         scrollPosition = $('#Leftpanel').scrollTop();  
     },
     close: function(event, ui ){
         scrollPosition = -1;     
     }
});
$('#Leftpanel').scroll(function(){
    if(scrollPosition != -1){
       $('#Leftpanel').scrollTop(scrollPosition); 
        $('#Wrapper').focus();
    }
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/9m2Qg/

Example 2 (improved scrolling)

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/9m2Qg/3/

Only tested on google chrome.

Comment: @user1837608 please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question or give feedback.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this solution does do the trick. One issue for me is that I have many inputs with different autocomplete values - so I would have to adapt the code to each instance, right?

Comment: I tried using the `appendTo` option onto my initial input, but that has no effect. Seems like that would be the ideal way to stick it!

Comment: @user1837608 I don't know that you would have to adapt the code to each instance.. If you can create another fiddle demonstrating the issue, if you are still having one I would be glad to look at it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because my fields are in a table. I fixed it like that

```
let input = $('.autocomplete');

input.autocomplete({
  appendTo: input.parents().eq(0),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto complete will append to the 'body' of the document by default. So you use jQuery `appendTo` to append auto-complete to your parent div instead.

Try this.

```
$("#textboxId").autocomplete({
   appendTo: "#parentId",   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem on project that I am working on, but instead of solution with appendTo that is mentioned in some other answers I decided to implement autocomplete the same way native combobox works. If parent div is scrolled, menu on autocomplete is closed. I achived this by adding onscroll event listener to parent div that closes menu (https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-close).

I choose this solution because if autocomplete is appended to parent div instead of body, and if it positioned in the lower part of div, sometimes scrollbar appears when menu on autocomplete is opened.