# How to properly override Jquery UI Styling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I'm using jquery autocomplete (+ jquery-ui.min.css), and I'm having issues with the styling. Most previous answers conclude with adding !important to the css, which I'd like to avoid.

Simple code (Autocomplete connects with the search-input id):

```
<div class="user-search">
  <form>
    <%= text_field_tag :user, params[:query], id: "search-input" %>
  </form>
</div>
```

However, viewing the dev tools, the this ul class, associated with autocomplete, gets pushed out of the containing div, just inside the body tag.

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content">
```

Is there a better way to override jquery ui styling?

Thanks!

Comment: The usual way to manage the widget's position is through [its `position` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-position), not via CSS. Can you add more details about your particular use case? The question as it stands a bit vague

Comment: Thanks @blgt I've updated the question to include the html. That's good to know. Do you suggest to override most the styling in the js file with options?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this selector:

```
.ui-autocomplete.ui-front.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  /* Overridden Styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PreveenKumar. That works for certain styles like background-color, however others, like position, top, width are all overridden by generated inline styles. Might you have suggestions?

Comment: Ah okay. I understand the issue now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're concerned about the menu's containment, so you're looking for is [the `appendTo` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo). From the documentation:

> the parents of the input field will be checked for a class of ui-front. If an element with the ui-front class is found, the menu will be appended to that element. Regardless of the value, if no element is found, the menu will be appended to the body.

So, to change that to the containing `form` element:

```
$("#search-input").autocomplete({
    // other options...
    appendTo: ".user-search > form"
});
```

For the scenario described there's no need to mess around with the CSS. Use caution if you do

ref. the list of options: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thats it! Thanks! Also found a similar good answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20817840/2956085